# How can I delete the selected record in mySQL from my HTML/PHP page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-delete

My idea is to click 'Delete' link and it will pass the id to another PHP page (deleteSession.php), and then execute the query in deleteSession.php. but I couldn't seems to get the id from manageSession.php

In **manageSession.php**,

```
<table align='center' border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>    
            <tr>
                <th>Session Id</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Date & Time</th>
                <th>Venue</th>
                <th>Pax</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT booking_id, booking_types, dates_sessions, venue_available, room_count FROM bookings_available ORDER BY dates_sessions asc";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
            //mysqli_close($link);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['booking_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['booking_types']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['dates_sessions']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['venue_available']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['room_count']; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="deleteSession.php?id=<?php echo $row['booking_id']; ?>"><input type="button" value="Delete"/></a></td>
                    <td><a href="editSession.php?id=<?php echo $row['booking_id']; ?>"><input type="button" value="Edit"/></a></td>
            </tr>
           <?php } ?>
        </table>
```

In **deleteSession.php**,

```
<?php
include "dbFunctions.php";
include "manageSession.php";

    //$sql = "SELECT booking_id, booking_types, dates_sessions, venue_available, room_count FROM bookings_available";
    //$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    $bookingId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'booking_id');

    $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM bookings_available WHERE booking_id = '$bookingId'";

?>
```

Comment: you have set your url parameters as `?id=` but searching for get GET index as `booking_id`

Comment: Hi Ghost, so should I change the booking_id to id in deleteSession.php, because I tried using ?booking_id in manageSession.php but it is not working either.

Comment: just make sure the url parameters in your anchor corresponds to the one your pointing out in your GET in `deleteSession`. and having a button inside an anchor is not valid HTML

Comment: and to point out the obvious (unless its a truncated code in your question). execute the query. Since you're using mysqli, why not use prepared statements.

Comment: Hi all, I had tried the all the methods that you guys had suggested but nothing works.

Comment: Hi Ghost, do you mean that there might be a problem with queries? I will look into that soon.

Comment: there is no problem in your DELETE query statement, your just not executing it. its just a variable, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Ghost, Right.
Use mysql_query($deleteQuery) or die('Unable to delete');

Comment: @EmiproTechnologies Technologies & Ghost, I had that line in my code now, but still not unable to delete. Please help.

Comment: @Bliven. Can you print query for debug? Just write `echo $deleteQuery;` And have you used `$bookingId = $_GET['id'];` ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologies I did what you had told me to, but still not able to delete the selected query.

Comment: @Bliven. Please paste your query text using `echo $deleteQuery;` here.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologies $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM bookings_available WHERE booking_id = '$bookingId'";

$deleteExecute = mysql_query($deleteQuery) or die('Unable to delete'); I then echo $deleteExecute at the html body.

Answer (score 0):

I think in deleteSession.php file code should be as follows.

```
$bookingId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
```

OR

```
$bookingId = $_GET['id'];
```

Because you are passing get parameter as follows.

`deleteSession.php?id=`

And also keep anchor as follows.

```
<a href="deleteSession.php?id=<?php echo $row['booking_id']; ?>">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the deleteSession.php you can try and replace:

```
$bookingId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'booking_id');
```

with the below code:

```
  $bookingId = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Finally at the last line you have to execute the query which is stored in $deleteQuery variable, which is not executed yet by using below code:

```
     $qry = mysql_query("DELETE FROM bookings_available WHERE booking_id = '$bookingId'");
    //will show you error if not able to delete
if(!$qry)
        die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this at line 3 and it works:

```
mysqli_select_db($link ,$DB);
```

Because in the code I have not selected the mysql database and also the query was not executing as the first parameter $link was missing.